# Order a list from low to high - Ionic

Tags: javascript, angular, sorting, typescript, ionic-framework

When a user searches they get a list of items that are included in their search, I cannot work out how to sort this from items that include the lowest amount first. Example I search "potato", "leek" I am returned all items that include this, but the first item may include 15 and next 5, I want the lowest to be listed first.

I have an Ion-list as below:

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-item *ngFor="let item of recipes" (click)="goToDetails(item.id)">
    <div class="thumb">
      <img src="{{item.smallImageUrls}}">
    </div>
    <div class="item-text">
      <div class="inner">
        <div class="title">
          <h1>{{item.recipeName}}</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="rating">
          <rating [(ngModel)]="item.rating"></rating>
        </div>
        <div class="time">
          <p>{{item.totalTimeInSeconds | HoursMinutesSeconds}} minutes</p>
        </div>
        <div class="ingredients">
          <p>{{item.ingredients.length}} Ingredients</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

I need to sort the whole list depending on

> item.ingredients.length

to sort from low to high by default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can't use pipe to sort them because in `*ngFor` you just have access to one element not to all of them to sort, then you should sort the whole array in your ts file then iterate on it :

```
recipes.sort(function(a,b){
  return a.ingredients.length - b.ingredients.length; 
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I was trying something similar but just got the syntax wrong

Answer (score 0):

I guess your `recipes` array is coming from a service. In your RecipeService you can sort that array.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
...
@Injectable()
export class RecipeService {
  ...
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getRecipes(): Observable<Recipe> {
    return this.http
      .get<Recipe[]>(`${url}`)
      .pipe(map(recipes: Array<Recipe>) => this.sortArray(recipes)), this.catchHttpErrors());
  }
  ...
  sortArray(arr: Array<Recipe>) {
    return arr.sort((a: Recipe, b: Recipe) => {
      if (a.ingredients.length < b.ingredients.length) {
        return -1;
      } else if (a.ingredients.length > b.ingredients.length) {
        return 1;
      }
      return 0;
    });
  }
}
```

or something like this...